# wrirting XSL to perform some operations on xml data

Tags: html, xml, xslt

How to write xsl in the body of products.xsl that will get product name and condition with quantity > 10

products.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>soaps</name>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
        <condition>ready</condition>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>soaps</name>
        <quantity>15</quantity>
        <condition>ready</condition>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>soaps</name>
        <quantity>20</quantity>
        <condition>ready</condition>
    </product>
</products>
```

products.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="products.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> products</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

products quantity greater than 10 : <BR/>


</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: please, check your example products.xml, the opening/closing tags for <products> don't seem right. If you use indentation, you will see that more easily.

Comment: I think you can use an if-case.

Comment: @ Amigable how to write XSL for doing this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Comment: Input is [updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866068/wrirting-xsl-to-perform-some-operations-on-xml-data "See duplicate question")

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/products/product">
  <xsl:if test="quantity > 10">
    <xsl:value-of select="name" />: <xsl:value-of select="condition" /> <br/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: There is no need for `xsl:if` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

This should work: (if provided with a well-formed XML – see comment on question)

```
<BODY> products quantity greater than 10 : <BR/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//product[quantity &gt; 10]"/>
</BODY>
```

Combined with e.g. this template:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <P>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="condition"/>
    </P>
</xsl:template>
```

Just customize per your needs…

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation** (no `<xsl:for-each>` and no conditional instructions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="product[quantity > 10]">
  <p>
    Product: <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    contition: <xsl:value-of select="condition"/>
    quantity: <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/>
  </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>soaps</name>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
        <condition>ready</condition>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>soaps</name>
        <quantity>15</quantity>
        <condition>ready</condition>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>soaps</name>
        <quantity>20</quantity>
        <condition>ready</condition>
    </product>
</products>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<p>
    Product: soaps
    contition: ready
    quantity: 15</p>
<p>
    Product: soaps
    contition: ready
    quantity: 20</p>
```