# wrirting XSL to perform some operations on xml data

Tags: html, xml, xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wrirting XSL to perform some operations on xml data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865221/wrirting-xsl-to-perform-some-operations-on-xml-data)

How to write xsl in the body of products.xsl that will get product name and condition where product quantity > 10

products.xml-----------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<products>
<product>
<name>soaps</name>
<quantity>10</quantity>
<condition>ready</condition>
</product>
<product>
<name>soaps</name>
<quantity>15</quantity>
<condition>ready</condition>
</product>
<product>
<name>soaps</name>
<quantity>20</quantity>
<condition>ready</condition>
</product>
</products>
```

products.xsl-------

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="products.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> products</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

products quantity greater than 10 : <BR/>


</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```